# How can I access data retrieved from a window?

Tags: powershell

Using the process described in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff730949(v=technet.10) I have created a script to allow me to select information from a database, and then return the information to the function that called it for later use.
The problem I have is that while the data seems to be selected when returned the calling `SelectBuildScript` function does not seem to be receiving it. This function is triggered by a button. The code below creates the button. When the button is pressed the dialogue opens allowing me to select the build file. But while on exiting that function the verbose for the function return data shows the data required. The one in the calling code is empty and I cannot see any returned data.

```
    $listButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $listButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(5,40)
    $listButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
    $listButton.Text = "List Build Scripts"

    $ListButton.Add_Click({($selectedBuild = SelectBuildScript -verbose)}) 
    $form.Controls.Add($listButton)
    ##end define list tab #########################################

    Write-Verbose "[$($MyInvocation.MyCommand)] Selected build = $selectedBuild build id = $selectedBuild[0] ver = $selectedBuild[1]"
```

How do I access data being returned from a dialogue for later use?

Would I be better off using global data to pass the data around.

---

Sorry about the delay in responding I have been working on something else.
I have modified the script to use global data which I thought would overcome the scoping problems and allow this to work. But I have had no change in script behavior because of the change. New script is like this.

```
    $listButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $listButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(5,40)
    $listButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
    $listButton.Text = "List Build Scripts"
#script now places return into global:selected_build
    $ListButton.Add_Click({(SelectBuildScript -verbose)}) 
    $form.Controls.Add($listButton)
    ##end define list tab #########################################

    Write-Verbose "[$($MyInvocation.MyCommand)] Selected build = $global:selected_Build build id = $global:selected_Build[0] ver = $global:selected_Build[1]"
```

The global has the correct data in the build script but not in the calling script. 
As I have a GUI calling a GUI, with the calling GUI trying to use the data selected in the called GUI, could this be a problem in the code order.

Comment: Just as you'd write to the GUI element in your form, you'd select data from the text property of the GUI element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684112/how-to-capture-textbox-data-using-powershell-and-windows-forms

Comment: I have put more information in the question. It does not seem to be a scope problem because using global data did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell scopes were not part of my earlier response.

As a rule, I keep code behind separate form GUI design.

```
<#
Environment Notes:

Any notes about this region 
#>

#region Begin code behind
# 
    # Function, module, namespace environment settings go here
# 
#endregion End Code Behind



<#
GUI Notes:

Any notes about this region 
#>
#region Begin GUI implementation
# 
    # All GUI elements go here
# 
#endregion End GUI implementation
```

If you have not proven that all the raw calls to a data source are valid, then don't spend any cycles doing it from a GUI.

This allows me or a GUI specialist to do whatever, and then I just bind my code to the elements/events by the function name.

That being said, create a function for what you want to do outside fo the GUI, then test that function to make sure you are getting what you'd expect, then use that function name in the GUI/Event element.

```
# Example

#region Begin code behind
# 
Function Get-ListButtonData
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    Param
    ()

    # Your function code here
}
# 
#endregion End Code Behind


#region Begin GUI implementation
# 
$listButton          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$listButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(5,40)
$listButton.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$listButton.Text     = "List Build Scripts"
$ListButton.Add_Click({Get-ListButtonData}) 
$form.Controls.Add($listButton)
##end define list tab #########################################
# 
#endregion End GUI implementation
```

This way, if you need to make the function do something different, you can do that without ever messing with the GUI, since it's just calling the function.